# ie 8 Zoom increasing zoom level distorts select box

Tags: html, internet-explorer-8, html-select, zooming

In IE 8, I have form elements. When the page is zoomed in (ctrl +) in `<select>`s alone not getting zoomed in properly.It looks like hidden half way and stays in same size (as in 100% zoom).

If I re- render the page it zooms in but it stays in the same size even after zooming out.

In IE9 it works fine. I need to support from IE8.

Any help!!

PS:As the page should be accessible, we are meant to support various zoom levels.

Comment: Can this help you http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/dynimg/IC266036.jpg ?

Comment: Thanks, I will try that but it will for resetting I guess. For the issue when zooming in ? i.e. it is not getting zoomed.

Comment: Look few options above, there's one marked with *, which says when zooming as well.

Comment: Thanks. I tried both and no use. it is still behaving in the same way.